# Fill percent of UIImageView from full UIImage with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an `UIImageView` named `bigBottle`:

```
bigBottle.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"fullBootle.png"];
```

`fullBootle.png` is a bottle filled up to 100%.

I need two steps:

1. First make a crop of image with percent (let`s say 50% fill ) - that is, a bottle filled up to half, from the **bottom**).
2. Animate `bigBottle` to creeate a filling effect from down of the bottle to 50% fill.
   My code is bellow:

   ```
   CGRect captureRect = CGRectMake(0,22,18,72);
   UIImage *captureImg;
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(captureRect.size);
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   [self.bigBottle.layer renderInContext:context];
   captureImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   self.bigBottle.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(captureImg.CGImage,
   captureRect)];
   CGRect captureRect1 = CGRectMake(0,37,18,72);
   self.bigBottle.frame=CGRectMake(45, 174,18,1);
   CGRect newFrameOfMyView1 = CGRectMake(45,129, 18, 45);
   [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
       animations:^{
           self.bigBottle.frame = newFrameOfMyView1;
       }
       completion:^(BOOL finished){
           NSLog( @"done bottle: 1" );
   }];
   ```

It is another way to make this animation of filling the bottle more simple, and more memory efficient? I have dozens of bottles to fill random with percent (let`s say bottle80 is 20% filled up) and to not have blurred resulting images ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my simple implementation to your question. Create a new subclass of CALayer and implement a dynamic property called percent and then animate it as,

**ImageLayer.h**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ImageLayer : CALayer
  @property (nonatomic,assign )float percent;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageName;
@end
```

**ImageLayer.m**

```
#import "ImageLayer.h"

@implementation ImageLayer
@dynamic percent;


+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key{
  if([key isEqualToString:@"percent"]){
    return YES;
  }else
    return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}


- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{
  UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bottle.jpg"];
  [image drawInRect:self.bounds];
  float heightToBeCovered =  self.percent * CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds);
  float verticalYPosition = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - heightToBeCovered;
  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, verticalYPosition, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), heightToBeCovered )];
  [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
  [path fill];
  UIGraphicsPopContext();
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  ImageLayer *imageLayer = [ImageLayer layer];
  imageLayer.position = self.view.center;
  imageLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
  [self.view.layer addSublayer:imageLayer];
  CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"percent"];
  [animation setFromValue:@1];
  [animation setToValue:@0];

  [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
  [animation setDuration:10.0];
  [imageLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"imageAnimation"];


}

@end
```

Comment: Thenk you. I still don't have enough points to vote up, but I'll do it soon.

Comment: Well, your example fills a rectangle and I used animation.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards; to keep result visible. Please take a look to this screen-shot. It is indeed the final stage of the kind of animation I need. So, the bottles are filled up from bottom to top, starting with 1 height, and the fill respects the full bottle contour. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2h7lzs4&s=8

Answer (score 0):

No, I just make this fill-up with simple animation:

```
self.bigBottle.frame =CGRectMake(self.bigBottle.frame.origin.x,self.bigBottle.frame.origin.y + self.bigBottle.frame.size.height,18,0); /*so the height is 0 on start*/
[self.bigBottle setClipsToBounds:YES]; //so image will be bounds to UIImageView bounds
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{ self.bigBottle.frame =CGRectMake(self.bigBottle.frame.origin.x,self.bigBottle.frame.origin.y -43 ,18,self.bigBottle.frame.size.height+43); //where 43 is a value I generate random
```