# How to make a image little by little appear from left bottom corner to top right corner of that image

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have an UIImage
[image]

And I want to make it animate slowly from left bottom corner to top right corner of that image.

Comment: You can do it by taking multiple sequence image and change image on some interval.

Comment: @kb920 He is talking about animations.

Comment: @kb920 I don't want to use gif image. It's my last solution

Comment: I am not saying to use gif image. it should be a normal image.

Comment: Multiple image is same as gif image :(

Comment: @MR.Hoang this question has been asked several times. Feel free to read the links or search for the other answers in similiar questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870479/moving-uiview-from-bottom-to-top

Comment: @Sneak No, I'm not move a uiimageview, I just want to show it with animation

Comment: @Mr.Hoang Then check here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973908/fill-percent-of-uiimageview-from-full-uiimage-with-animation the question has already been asked many times. **search for it** before you ask, there are many threads about it.

Comment: @Sneak OK, I'll try, but I spent more time to search for it before ask this question. May be, my keyword is not exactly yet!

Comment: @Mr.Hoang Read the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973908/fill-percent-of-uiimageview-from-full-uiimage-with-animation thats your solution.